# Maximum length of select statement in Hive

Tags: database, linux, unix, hadoop, hive

I am trying to do a

```
select
  count(distinct(col_name1  )),
  count(distinct(col_name2  )),
  count(distinct(col_name3  )),
      .......... 
  count(distinct(col_name804))
from 
  tab_name;
```

The query doesn't seem to run on hive.
It is throwing an out of memory exception error.
Is there a limit on the maximum number of columns that hive can handle?
Or any help on why the error is coming?

Thanks

The error log is as follows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rhive_row":"1138","f16":43,"f17":"S","f18":43,"f19":null,"f20":"","f21":0,"f22":"H","f23":null,"f24":"","f25":3,"f26":"F","f27":"01","f28":null,"f29":null,"f30":null,"f31":null,"f32":null,"f33":null,"f34":"","f35":null,"f36":null,"f37":null,"f38":"","f39":"","f40":null,"f41":null,"f42":null,"f43":"","f44":null,"f45":null,"f46":"","f47":"","f48":"","f49":null,"f50":null,"f51":null,"f52":null,"f53":null,"f54":null,"f55":null,"f56":null,"f57":null,"f58":null,"f59":null,"f60":null,"f61":null,"f62":null,"f63":"","f64":"","f65":"","f66":null,"f67":null,"f68":null,"f69":null,"f70":null,"f71":"","f72":null,"f73":null,"f74":"","f75":"","f76":"","f77":null,"f78":null,"f79":"","f80":null,"f81":null,"f82":null,"f83":"","f84":null,"f85":"","f86":null,"f87":null,"f88":null,"f89":"","f90":null,"f91":null,"f92":null,"f93":null,"f94":null,"f95":null,"f96":null,"f97":null,"f98":null,"f99":null,"f100":null,"f101":"","f102":"","f103":null,"f104":null,"f105":null,"f106":null,"f107":"","f108":"","f109":null,"f110":"","f111":"","f112":"","f113":null,"f114":null,"f115":null,"f116":null,"f117":"","f118":null,"f119":"","f120":null,"f121":null,"f122":null,"f123":null,"f124":null,"f125":null,"f126":null,"f127":null,"f128":null,"f129":null,"f130":null,"f131":"","f132":null,"f133":null,"f134":null,"f135":null,"f136":null,"f137":"","f138":"","f139":null,"f140":"","f141":null,"f142":"","f143":null,"f144":"","f145":null,"f146":null,"f147":null,"f148":null,"f149":null,"f150":null,"f151":null,"f152":null,"f153":null,"f154":null,"f155":null,"f156":null,"f157":null,"f158":null,"f159":null,"f160":"","f161":"","f162":null,"f163":"","f164":null,"f165":"","f166":null,"f167":null,"f168":"","f169":null,"f170":null,"f171":"","f172":"","f173":"","f174":null,"f175":null,"f176":"","f177":null,"f178":null,"f179":null,"f180":null,"f181":null,"f182":"","f183":"","f184":null,"f185":null,"f186":null,"f187":null,"f188":"","f189":"","f190":"","f191":"","f192":"","f193":null,"f194":"","f195":null,"f196":null,"f197":null,"f198":null,"f199":"","f200":null,"f201":"","f202":null,"f203":"","f204":"","f205":"","f206":null,"f207":null,"f208":"","f209":null,"f210":null,"f211":null,"f212":"","f213":null,"f214":"","f215":null,"f216":null,"f217":null,"f218":null,"f219":null,"f220":null,"f221":null,"f222":null,"f223":null,"f224":null,"f225":null,"f226":"","f227":null,"f228":null,"f229":"","f230":null,"f231":"","f232":"","f233":null,"f234":"","f235":null,"f236":"","f237":null,"f238":"","f239":"","f240":"","f241":null,"f242":null,"f243":"","f244":"","f245":"","f246":null,"f247":"","f248":"","f249":null,"f250":"","f251":null,"f252":"","f253":"","f254":null,"f255":"","f256":"","f257":null,"f258":"","f259":"","f260":null,"f261":"","f262":"","f263":"","f264":null,"f265":"","f266":null,"f267":null,"f268":"","f269":"","f270":"","f271":"","f272":"","f273":null,"f274":null,"f275":"","f276":null,"f277":"","f278":"","f279":null,"f280":"","f281":"","f282":"","f283":null,"f284":null,"f285":"","f286":"","f287":null,"f288":null,"f289":"","f290":"","f291":"","f292":null,"f293":"","f294":null,"f295":"","f296":null,"f297":"","f298":null,"f299":null,"f300":null,"f301":null,"f302":null,"f303":null,"f304":null,"f305":null,"f306":null,"f307":null,"f308":null,"f309":null,"f310":null,"f311":null,"f312":null,"f313":null,"f314":null,"f315":null,"f316":null,"f317":null,"f318":null,"f319":null,"f320":null,"f321":null,"f322":null,"f323":null,"f324":null,"f325":null,"f326":null,"f327":null,"f328":null,"f329":null,"f330":null,"f331":null,"f332":null,"f333":null,"f334":null,"f335":null,"f336":null,"f337":null,"f338":null,"f339":null,"f340":null,"f341":null,"f342":null,"f343":null,"f344":null,"f345":null,"f346":null,"f347":null,"f348":null,"f349":null,"f350":null,"f351":null,"f352":null,"f353":null,"f354":null,"f355":null,"f356":null,"f357":null,"f358":null,"f359":null,"f360":null,"f361":null,"f362":null,"f363":null,"f364":null,"f365":null,"f366":null,"f367":null,"f368":null,"f369":null,"f370":null,"f371":null,"f372":null,"f373":null,"f374":null,"f375":null,"f376":null,"f377":null,"f378":null,"f379":null,"f380":null,"f381":null,"f382":null,"f383":null,"f384":null,"f385":null,"f386":null,"f387":null,"f388":null,"f389":null,"f390":null,"f391":null,"f392":null,"f393":"","f394":"","f395":null,"f396":"","f397":null,"f398":null,"f399":null,"f400":"","f401":"","f402":null,"f403":null,"f404":null,"f405":null,"f406":null,"f407":null,"f408":null,"f409":"S","f410":"N","f411":"","f412":"K","f413":0,"f414":350,"f415":"N","f416":"N","f417":null,"f418":"N","f419":"","f420":7,"f421":1940,"f422":null,"f423":0,"f424":0,"f425":null,"f426":"","f427":1,"f428":2,"f429":"1920-09-07","f430":0,"f431":3,"f432":6,"f433":null,"f434":0,"f435":"","f436":"","f437":"N","f438":5,"f439":1,"f440":0,"f441":"","f442":"E","f443":5,"f444":1,"f445":2,"f446":80,"f447":null,"f448":"I","f449":"N","f450":"A","f451":"","f452":"N","f453":null,"f454":"Y","f455":14,"f456":"","f457":"","f458":0,"f459":null,"f460":5,"f461":9,"f462":2,"f463":2,"f464":1,"f465":"","f466":0,"f467":0,"f468":0,"f469":0,"f470":0,"f471":0,"f472":4,"f473":5,"f474":1,"f475":1,"f476":0,"f477":0,"f478":0,"f479":0,"f480":19,"f481":0,"f482":2,"f483":0,"f484":0,"f485":52,"f486":627092,"f487":4,"f488":14,"f489":4,"f490":3,"f491":7,"f492":520,"f493":3,"f494":704678,"f495":74,"f496":281,"f497":520,"f498":0,"f499":390,"f500":945,"f501":2,"f502":3,"f503":2,"f504":107966,"f505":6,"f506":5,"f507":0,"f508":0,"f509":0,"f510":0,"f511":0,"f512":0,"f513":0,"f514":0,"f515":0,"f516":0,"f517":0,"f518":0,"f519":0,"f520":0,"f521":0,"f522":0,"f523":0,"f524":0,"f525":0,"f526":0,"f527":0,"f528":0,"f529":0,"f530":0,"f531":"","f532":"","f533":"","f534":"","f535":"","f536":"","f537":"N","f538":0,"f539":0,"f540":1,"f541":1,"f542":null,"f543":null,"f544":null,"f545":null,"f546":null,"f547":null,"f548":null,"f549":null,"f550":null,"f551":null,"f552":null,"f553":null,"f554":null,"f555":null,"f556":null,"f557":null,"f558":null,"f559":null,"f560":0,"f561":5,"f562":1,"f563":2,"f564":0,"f565":0,"f566":null,"f567":"","f568":"N","f569":null,"f570":null,"f571":null,"f572":null,"f573":null,"f574":"H","f575":"","f576":null,"f577":0,"f578":0,"f579":0,"f580":0,"f581":0,"f582":0,"f583":0,"f584":0,"f585":0,"f586":"","f587":"","f588":"","f589":"","f590":null,"f591":null,"f592":null,"f593":null,"f594":null,"f595":null,"f596":"","f597":"","f598":null,"f599":"","f600":"","f601":null,"f602":"","f603":"","f604":null,"f605":0,"f606":5,"f607":1,"f608":"Y","f609":"","f610":"","f611":"S","f612":3,"f613":1,"f614":null,"f615":"","f616":"","f617":0,"f618":0,"f619":null,"f620":null,"f621":null,"f622":null,"f623":"","f624":"U","f625":"K","f626":0,"f627":196608,"f628":43,"f629":"F","f630":"H","f631":43,"f632":null,"f633":"","f634":3,"f635":null,"f636":"","f637":"01","f638":"P","f639":"S","f640":null,"f641":0,"f642":"01","f643":"","f644":"Y","f645":"","f646":"","f647":"","f648":"","f649":"","f650":null,"f651":null,"f652":"","f653":"","f654":"","f655":"","f656":"","f657":"","f658":null,"f659":null,"f660":"","f661":null,"f662":"","f663":"","f664":"","f665":null,"f666":null,"f667":null,"f668":null,"f669":"","f670":null,"f671":"","f672":"","f673":null,"f674":"","f675":"","f676":null,"f677":"","f678":"","f679":"","f680":"","f681":null,"f682":null,"f683":"","f684":null,"f685":"","f686":"","f687":null,"f688":null,"f689":"","f690":"","f691":null,"f692":null,"f693":null,"f694":"","f695":null,"f696":"","f697":"","f698":"","f699":"","f700":"","f701":null,"f702":"","f703":"","f704":null,"f705":"","f706":"","f707":"","f708":"","f709":null,"f710":null,"f711":"","f712":null,"f713":"","f714":null,"f715":0,"f716":1,"f717":0,"f718":0,"f719":0,"f720":1,"f721":0,"f722":0,"f723":1,"f724":0,"f725":0,"f726":0,"f727":0,"f728":0,"f729":null,"f730":null,"f731":null,"f732":null,"f733":null,"f734":null,"f735":null,"f736":null,"f737":null,"f738":null,"f739":null,"f740":null,"f741":null,"f742":null,"f743":null,"f744":null,"f745":null,"f746":null,"f747":null,"f748":null,"f749":null,"f750":null,"f751":null,"f752":null,"f753":null,"f754":null,"f755":null,"f756":null,"f757":null,"f758":null,"f759":null,"f760":null,"f761":null,"f762":null,"f763":null,"f764":null,"f765":null,"f766":null,"f767":null,"f768":null,"f769":null,"f770":null,"f771":15,"f772":"Y","f773":"N","f774":null,"f775":"N","f776":"N","f777":null,"f778":"N","f779":"N","f780":"NY","f781":10021,"f782":3518,"f783":36,"f784":11,"f785":47229,"f786":"A04","f787":"B","f788":2,"f789":5,"f790":67,"f791":32,"f792":9969,"f793":0,"f794":65,"f795":"9","f796":74,"f797":2,"f798":100,"f799":61,"f800":"","f801":501,"f802":52,"f803":11,"f804":10,"f805":3,"f806":"N","f807":"N","f808":"N","f809":"C291","f810":"S","f811":1,"f812":550425,"f813":94,"f814":46,"f815":36,"f816":1,"f817":"A","f818":0,"f819":41,"f820":"W","f821":5600}
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:161)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:435)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:371)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
                at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"rhive_row":"1138","f16":43,"f17":"S","f18":43,"f19":null,"f20":"","f21":0,"f22":"H","f23":null,"f24":"","f25":3,"f26":"F","f27":"01","f28":null,"f29":null,"f30":null,"f31":null,"f32":null,"f33":null,"f34":"","f35":null,"f36":null,"f37":null,"f38":"","f39":"","f40":null,"f41":null,"f42":null,"f43":"","f44":null,"f45":null,"f46":"","f47":"","f48":"","f49":null,"f50":null,"f51":null,"f52":null,"f53":null,"f54":null,"f55":null,"f56":null,"f57":null,"f58":null,"f59":null,"f60":null,"f61":null,"f62":null,"f63":"","f64":"","f65":"","f66":null,"f67":null,"f68":null,"f69":null,"f70":null,"f71":"","f72":null,"f73":null,"f74":"","f75":"","f76":"","f77":null,"f78":null,"f79":"","f80":null,"f81":null,"f82":null,"f83":"","f84":null,"f85":"","f86":null,"f87":null,"f88":null,"f89":"","f90":null,"f91":null,"f92":null,"f93":null,"f94":null,"f95":null,"f96":null,"f97":null,"f98":null,"f99":null,"f100":null,"f101":"","f102":"","f103":null,"f104":null,"f105":null,"f106":null,"f107":"","f108":"","f109":null,"f110":"","f111":"","f112":"","f113":null,"f114":null,"f115":null,"f116":null,"f117":"","f118":null,"f119":"","f120":null,"f121":null,"f122":null,"f123":null,"f124":null,"f125":null,"f126":null,"f127":null,"f128":null,"f129":null,"f130":null,"f131":"","f132":null,"f133":null,"f134":null,"f135":null,"f136":null,"f137":"","f138":"","f139":null,"f140":"","f141":null,"f142":"","f143":null,"f144":"","f145":null,"f146":null,"f147":null,"f148":null,"f149":null,"f150":null,"f151":null,"f152":null,"f153":null,"f154":null,"f155":null,"f156":null,"f157":null,"f158":null,"f159":null,"f160":"","f161":"","f162":null,"f163":"","f164":null,"f165":"","f166":null,"f167":null,"f168":"","f169":null,"f170":null,"f171":"","f172":"","f173":"","f174":null,"f175":null,"f176":"","f177":null,"f178":null,"f179":null,"f180":null,"f181":null,"f182":"","f183":"","f184":null,"f185":null,"f186":null,"f187":null,"f188":"","f189":"","f190":"","f191":"","f192":"","f193":null,"f194":"","f195":null,"f196":null,"f197":null,"f198":null,"f199":"","f200":null,"f201":"","f202":null,"f203":"","f204":"","f205":"","f206":null,"f207":null,"f208":"","f209":null,"f210":null,"f211":null,"f212":"","f213":null,"f214":"","f215":null,"f216":null,"f217":null,"f218":null,"f219":null,"f220":null,"f221":null,"f222":null,"f223":null,"f224":null,"f225":null,"f226":"","f227":null,"f228":null,"f229":"","f230":null,"f231":"","f232":"","f233":null,"f234":"","f235":null,"f236":"","f237":null,"f238":"","f239":"","f240":"","f241":null,"f242":null,"f243":"","f244":"","f245":"","f246":null,"f247":"","f248":"","f249":null,"f250":"","f251":null,"f252":"","f253":"","f254":null,"f255":"","f256":"","f257":null,"f258":"","f259":"","f260":null,"f261":"","f262":"","f263":"","f264":null,"f265":"","f266":null,"f267":null,"f268":"","f269":"","f270":"","f271":"","f272":"","f273":null,"f274":null,"f275":"","f276":null,"f277":"","f278":"","f279":null,"f280":"","f281":"","f282":"","f283":null,"f284":null,"f285":"","f286":"","f287":null,"f288":null,"f289":"","f290":"","f291":"","f292":null,"f293":"","f294":null,"f295":"","f296":null,"f297":"","f298":null,"f299":null,"f300":null,"f301":null,"f302":null,"f303":null,"f304":null,"f305":null,"f306":null,"f307":null,"f308":null,"f309":null,"f310":null,"f311":null,"f312":null,"f313":null,"f314":null,"f315":null,"f316":null,"f317":null,"f318":null,"f319":null,"f320":null,"f321":null,"f322":null,"f323":null,"f324":null,"f325":null,"f326":null,"f327":null,"f328":null,"f329":null,"f330":null,"f331":null,"f332":null,"f333":null,"f334":null,"f335":null,"f336":null,"f337":null,"f338":null,"f339":null,"f340":null,"f341":null,"f342":null,"f343":null,"f344":null,"f345":null,"f346":null,"f347":null,"f348":null,"f349":null,"f350":null,"f351":null,"f352":null,"f353":null,"f354":null,"f355":null,"f356":null,"f357":null,"f358":null,"f359":null,"f360":null,"f361":null,"f362":null,"f363":null,"f364":null,"f365":null,"f366":null,"f367":null,"f368":null,"f369":null,"f370":null,"f371":null,"f372":null,"f373":null,"f374":null,"f375":null,"f376":null,"f377":null,"f378":null,"f379":null,"f380":null,"f381":null,"f382":null,"f383":null,"f384":null,"f385":null,"f386":null,"f387":null,"f388":null,"f389":null,"f390":null,"f391":null,"f392":null,"f393":"","f394":"","f395":null,"f396":"","f397":null,"f398":null,"f399":null,"f400":"","f401":"","f402":null,"f403":null,"f404":null,"f405":null,"f406":null,"f407":null,"f408":null,"f409":"S","f410":"N","f411":"","f412":"K","f413":0,"f414":350,"f415":"N","f416":"N","f417":null,"f418":"N","f419":"","f420":7,"f421":1940,"f422":null,"f423":0,"f424":0,"f425":null,"f426":"","f427":1,"f428":2,"f429":"1920-09-07","f430":0,"f431":3,"f432":6,"f433":null,"f434":0,"f435":"","f436":"","f437":"N","f438":5,"f439":1,"f440":0,"f441":"","f442":"E","f443":5,"f444":1,"f445":2,"f446":80,"f447":null,"f448":"I","f449":"N","f450":"A","f451":"","f452":"N","f453":null,"f454":"Y","f455":14,"f456":"","f457":"","f458":0,"f459":null,"f460":5,"f461":9,"f462":2,"f463":2,"f464":1,"f465":"","f466":0,"f467":0,"f468":0,"f469":0,"f470":0,"f471":0,"f472":4,"f473":5,"f474":1,"f475":1,"f476":0,"f477":0,"f478":0,"f479":0,"f480":19,"f481":0,"f482":2,"f483":0,"f484":0,"f485":52,"f486":627092,"f487":4,"f488":14,"f489":4,"f490":3,"f491":7,"f492":520,"f493":3,"f494":704678,"f495":74,"f496":281,"f497":520,"f498":0,"f499":390,"f500":945,"f501":2,"f502":3,"f503":2,"f504":107966,"f505":6,"f506":5,"f507":0,"f508":0,"f509":0,"f510":0,"f511":0,"f512":0,"f513":0,"f514":0,"f515":0,"f516":0,"f517":0,"f518":0,"f519":0,"f520":0,"f521":0,"f522":0,"f523":0,"f524":0,"f525":0,"f526":0,"f527":0,"f528":0,"f529":0,"f530":0,"f531":"","f532":"","f533":"","f534":"","f535":"","f536":"","f537":"N","f538":0,"f539":0,"f540":1,"f541":1,"f542":null,"f543":null,"f544":null,"f545":null,"f546":null,"f547":null,"f548":null,"f549":null,"f550":null,"f551":null,"f552":null,"f553":null,"f554":null,"f555":null,"f556":null,"f557":null,"f558":null,"f559":null,"f560":0,"f561":5,"f562":1,"f563":2,"f564":0,"f565":0,"f566":null,"f567":"","f568":"N","f569":null,"f570":null,"f571":null,"f572":null,"f573":null,"f574":"H","f575":"","f576":null,"f577":0,"f578":0,"f579":0,"f580":0,"f581":0,"f582":0,"f583":0,"f584":0,"f585":0,"f586":"","f587":"","f588":"","f589":"","f590":null,"f591":null,"f592":null,"f593":null,"f594":null,"f595":null,"f596":"","f597":"","f598":null,"f599":"","f600":"","f601":null,"f602":"","f603":"","f604":null,"f605":0,"f606":5,"f607":1,"f608":"Y","f609":"","f610":"","f611":"S","f612":3,"f613":1,"f614":null,"f615":"","f616":"","f617":0,"f618":0,"f619":null,"f620":null,"f621":null,"f622":null,"f623":"","f624":"U","f625":"K","f626":0,"f627":196608,"f628":43,"f629":"F","f630":"H","f631":43,"f632":null,"f633":"","f634":3,"f635":null,"f636":"","f637":"01","f638":"P","f639":"S","f640":null,"f641":0,"f642":"01","f643":"","f644":"Y","f645":"","f646":"","f647":"","f648":"","f649":"","f650":null,"f651":null,"f652":"","f653":"","f654":"","f655":"","f656":"","f657":"","f658":null,"f659":null,"f660":"","f661":null,"f662":"","f663":"","f664":"","f665":null,"f666":null,"f667":null,"f668":null,"f669":"","f670":null,"f671":"","f672":"","f673":null,"f674":"","f675":"","f676":null,"f677":"","f678":"","f679":"","f680":"","f681":null,"f682":null,"f683":"","f684":null,"f685":"","f686":"","f687":null,"f688":null,"f689":"","f690":"","f691":null,"f692":null,"f693":null,"f694":"","f695":null,"f696":"","f697":"","f698":"","f699":"","f700":"","f701":null,"f702":"","f703":"","f704":null,"f705":"","f706":"","f707":"","f708":"","f709":null,"f710":null,"f711":"","f712":null,"f713":"","f714":null,"f715":0,"f716":1,"f717":0,"f718":0,"f719":0,"f720":1,"f721":0,"f722":0,"f723":1,"f724":0,"f725":0,"f726":0,"f727":0,"f728":0,"f729":null,"f730":null,"f731":null,"f732":null,"f733":null,"f734":null,"f735":null,"f736":null,"f737":null,"f738":null,"f739":null,"f740":null,"f741":null,"f742":null,"f743":null,"f744":null,"f745":null,"f746":null,"f747":null,"f748":null,"f749":null,"f750":null,"f751":null,"f752":null,"f753":null,"f754":null,"f755":null,"f756":null,"f757":null,"f758":null,"f759":null,"f760":null,"f761":null,"f762":null,"f763":null,"f764":null,"f765":null,"f766":null,"f767":null,"f768":null,"f769":null,"f770":null,"f771":15,"f772":"Y","f773":"N","f774":null,"f775":"N","f776":"N","f777":null,"f778":"N","f779":"N","f780":"NY","f781":10021,"f782":3518,"f783":36,"f784":11,"f785":47229,"f786":"A04","f787":"B","f788":2,"f789":5,"f790":67,"f791":32,"f792":9969,"f793":0,"f794":65,"f795":"9","f796":74,"f797":2,"f798":100,"f799":61,"f800":"","f801":501,"f802":52,"f803":11,"f804":10,"f805":3,"f806":"N","f807":"N","f808":"N","f809":"C291","f810":"S","f811":1,"f812":550425,"f813":94,"f814":46,"f815":36,"f816":1,"f817":"A","f818":0,"f819":41,"f820":"W","f821":5600}
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:550)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:143)
                ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -128
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:737)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:83)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:531)
                ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -128
                at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:338)
                at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:351)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.binarysortable.BinarySortableSerDe.serialize(BinarySortableSerDe.java:661)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.binarysortable.BinarySortableSerDe.serialize(BinarySortableSerDe.java:485)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator.processOp(ReduceSinkOperator.java:276)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:959)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.flush(GroupByOperator.java:926)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processHashAggr(GroupByOperator.java:779)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:722)
                ... 18 more
```

Comment: What version of hive are you using?

Comment: The hive version i am using is hive-0.7.1

I was trying to find the number of maximum count(distinct()) I could call on the columns in a select statement, I found out that by trying that the task fails over 128 columns.

Now I wanted to know, if this value is right , and if it is right can it be controlled by the user

Comment: Well 128 is a suspicious number (maximum value of a byte is 127, and adding one wraps the value to -128). It would probably require digging through the source to confirm this.

Comment: I was also skeptical that the value would be 128, I tried it twice on two different machines.

Comment: Will you be able to dig up the source and find out?
I am not really sure how to dig through the source code.

Comment: Are you sure its hive-0.7.1 - the BinarySortableSerDe.java doesn't have 661 lines of code? http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hive/tags/release-0.7.1/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/binarysortable/BinarySortableSerDe.java?view=markup

Comment: I have two machines with hive installed, one is 0.7.1 the other is 0.8.0 both were getting similar errors. I think this log might be from the 0.8.0 version then.

Comment: Yes that error was taken from the hive-0.8.0 installation.
I tried my last run on that machine and the error logs pasted are from that installation